# Django, nginx and gunicorn in kubernetes

Tags: django, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I am trying to run my django app in kubernetes.I use docker-compose to build application and nginx.I am able to run the application using proxy server nginx in docker compose.

docker-compose build - successful

docker-compose up - successful

http://aggre.mabh.io - successful(able to load the application)

when i try to deploy the image of application and nginx,
I am getting error in kubernetes dashboard saying

**Error in kubernetes**

**pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times) (for both nginx and application)**

I am using **kompose up** to build and deploy the application.

How to deploy the the application in kubernetes and access the application through nginx kubernetes external end-point?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    image: sigmaaggregator/djangoapp
    labels:
      - kompose.service.type=NodePort
    volumes:
      - .:/djangoapp
      - static_volume:/djangoapp/static
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/djangoapp/static
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir -p /djangoapp
WORKDIR /djangoapp
COPY . /djangoapp

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy our project code
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"

# expose the port 4000
EXPOSE 4000

# define the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":4000", "aggre.wsgi:application"]
```

**config/nginx/conf.d/local.conf**

```
upstream hello_server {
   server djangoapp:4000;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name aggre.mabh.io;

   location /static/ {
     alias /djangoapp/static/;
   }

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://hello_server;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` objects, do they exist in your k8s cluster: `kubectl get pv -o wide`, `kubectl get pvc -o wide`?

Comment: Thank you @mk_sta. `PersistentVolumeClaim` objects are exist but they are in pending status. `PersistentVolume` is not exist.

Comment: Can you share `PV` and `PVC` events: `kubectl describe pv <PV-name>`, `kubectl describe pvc <PVC-name>`?

Answer (score 0):

For static files with django on kubernetes, consider whitenoise http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/ to provide a solution here.

This is a straightforward recommendation, but I spent much time searching around before I found it referenced.